# Is it possible to have a function in another function

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is it possible to have such a function:

```
Function First(test1 as string)
 second 'Hello'
....
  Function second( test2 as string)
  ....
  End Function
...
End Function
```

I try do do this but befor the end of the second function I am getting this error:
 `Expected End Function`

Comment: No but you can put second() before First()

Comment: No nested functions in VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Alex was saying you cannot nest functions. You can have the function declarations declared seperatly and still get the desired result.

```
Function second( test2 as string)
    ....
End Function

Function First(test1 as string)
    second 'Hello'
    ....
End Function
```

The function needs to be declared before it is called which is why you have the second before the first.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have nested function, this is an indication that what you're really looking for is a class with a private function. I'm assuming that you want to do this so that the second function is not visible outside of the first. This is about proper scoping.

Add a class module and declare function first as public.

```
Public Function First(test1 as string)
    First = Second(test1)
End Function

Private Function Second(test2 as String)
    "Hello there"
End Function
```

This will encapsulate the logic and `Second` will not be visible outside of the class it belongs to.